# How to install and use cpptest unit testing framework for c++

Tags: c++

I have installed [cpptest](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpptest/) on linux (Ubuntu 16.04),Step to install.

```
$ cd cpptest-1.1.2/

$ ./configure

$ make

$ sudo make install.
```

Installation dumped some .so and .a file in user/local/lib now I want to use class "Suite" defined in .so. How to use it.

Sample C++ code[image]

Comment: Can you try the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889799/libraries-in-usr-local-lib-not-found

Comment: Thanks Karel, I have modified question. See sample c++ code which is done on Windows

Comment: @karel That is the way specified in the github repo. I am glad there is a way to do it in ubuntu directly. Could you confirm those are the correct commands (I search and there is not so much info on this)

Comment: @PravinHolkar I am not sure I understand your question. You have been able to install cpptest right? so what is the problem? the usage?

Comment: @KansaiRobot It's the same commands as here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1030/ which are also the sane commands as in the INSTALL.quick.in file from the official cpptest GitHub repository: https://github.com/cpptest/cpptest